# Perl, sed, or awk one-liner to change the format of the file

Tags: regex, perl, unix, sed, awk

I need advice on how to change the file formatted following way
file1:

```
A       504688
B       jobnameA
A       504690
B       jobnameB
A       504691
B       jobnameC
...
```

into file2:

```
A       B
504688  jobnameA
504690  jobnameB
504691  jobnameC
...
```

One solution I could think of is:

```
cat file1 | perl -0777 -p -e 's/\s+B/\t/' | awk '{print $2"\t"$3}'.
```

But I am wondering if there is more efficient way or already known practice that does this job.

Comment: thank you very much mat. I recently joined to the community. I will do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 perl -nawe 'print "@F[1 .. $#F]", $F[0] eq "A" ? "\t" : "\n"' < /tmp/ab
```

Look up the options in [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Another useful one to add is `-l` (append newline to print), but not in this case.

Comment: @briandfoy - Thanks - but it's really just a one-liner. And rest assured that I did read [your book](http://amzn.com/0321496949)! :) And I can highly recommend it!

Comment: Thank you for answer! Btw, is the "<" toward the end really needed? I tried it without it, and it still works. What does it do? I am only familiar with > for directing the output..

Comment: The `<` is shell syntax (Bash and others on UNIX, as well as `cmd.exe`/Windows) for standard input (`STDIN`) redirection. So in this case standard input is coming from the file. To understand why it works in Perl without this input redirection operator, read up on the [`<ARGV>` filehandle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Filters).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your input file is tab separated:

```
echo $'A\tB'
cut -f2 filename | paste - -
```

Should be pretty quick because this is exactly what [cut](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=cut) and [paste](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=paste) were written to do.

Comment: +1 - `paste` and `join` have never really made it into my permanent mental toolset, but this is probably the most machine-efficient solution. Variation for space-delimited file: `cut -b8- /tmp/ab | paste - -`

Comment: wow...this is extremely elegant. can you explain exactly what - - options do in the paste command? cygwin man page doesn't seem to be explicit.And also and is it flexible? meaning can I give more options such as paste(transpose) the 2 lines below ?

Comment: see http://man.cx/paste -- 'paste' takes filenames as arguments and joins corresponding lines. If "-" is given as a filename, then lines for that file are read from stdin. Since 2 dashes are in that command, one line will be read for "file 1" and another line will be read for "file 2" until all the input is consumed.

Comment: That is extremely neat. thanks for the crystal clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^A/{num=$2}/^B/{print num,$2}' file
```

Or, alternately,

```
awk '{num=$2;getline;print num,$2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an sed solution:

```
sed -e 'N' -e 's/A\s*\(.*\)\nB\s*\(.*\)/\1\t\2/' file
```

This version will also print the header at the top:

```
sed '1{h;s/.*/A\tB/p;g};N;s/A\s*\(.*\)\nB\s*\(.*\)/\1\t\2/' file
```

Or an alternative:

```
sed -n '/^A\s*/{s///;h};/^B\s*/{s///;H;g;s/\n/\t/p}' file
```

If your sed does not support semicolons as a command separator for the alternative:

```
sed -n '
/^A\s*/{       # if the line starts with "A"
s///             # remove the "A" and the whitespace
h                # copy the remainder into the hold space
}              # end if
/^B\s*/{       # if the line starts with "B"
s///             # remove the "B" and the whitespace 
H                # append pattern space to hold space
g                # copy hold space to pattern space
s/\n/\t/p        # replace newline with tab and print
}' file
```

This version will also print the header at the top:

```
sed -n '/^A\s*/{s///;h;1s/.*/A\tB/p};/^B\s*/{s///;H;g;s/\n/\t/p}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work with any header text, not just fixed **A** and **B** >>

```
awk '{a=$1;b=$2;getline;if(c!=1){print a,$1;c=1};print b,$2}' file1 >file2
```

...and it will print also **header row**

If you need `\t` separator, then use:

```
awk '{a=$1;b=$2;getline;if(c!=1){print a"\t"$1;c=1};print b"\t"$2}' file1 >file2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed -e '1i\A\tB' -e 'N;s/A\s*\(\S*\).*\nB\s*\(\S*\).*/\1\t\2/' file
```